# how to automatically convert \cases to \begin{cases} \end{cases}?

Tags: cases, workflow

Is there some smart macro I could add in the preamble to handle this LaTeX auto-generated code?

I use Maple's `latex()` command to convert results to LaTeX that I then compile using texlive in a separate document.

Sometimes it generates the wrong LaTeX or broken LaTeX. Here is an example of one such case:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The above output is send to a latex file and wrapped inside `\begin{equation}` and `\end{equation}`. I picked `equation` environment to put the result inside, but I can change this if it helps in conversions.

This is all done using an automated script. I do not use any of Maple style sheets or anything else. I simply just take the latex() output and process that using texlive standard setup.

I have hundreds of such equations, so manually editing any broken Maple LaTeX output is not possible and since each time I re-run the script the edits will be lost.

Is there a way to make a macro that will convert the above to use `\begin{cases}` with an enclosing `\end{cases}` using some smart replacement rule to make LaTeX and amsmath happy?

Here is the error, and a MWE:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

MWE

```
\documentclass[11pt,notitlepage]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
%smart renewcommand here? or \let?
\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
x-
\cases{-2\,\sqrt {-y \left( x \right) }&$y \left( x \right) \leq 0$\cr 
2\,\sqrt {y \left( x \right) }&$0<y \left( x \right) $\cr}+{\it \_C1}=0_{{1}}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

and

```
pdflatex foo.tex

(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/umsa.fd)
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/umsb.fd)

! Package amsmath Error: Old form `\cases' should be \begin{cases}.

See the amsmath package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.9 \cases
          {-2\,\sqrt {-y \left( x \right) }&$y \left( x \right) \leq 0$\cr
?
```

Comment: The “old form `\cases`” has nothing to do with `amsmath`; it is in the LaTeX kernel because it was in Plain TeX. I'm quite surprised that Maple uses that deprecated form, as the `cases` environment was included in the original `amslatex` back in 1990.

Comment: @egreg thanks. I know little about these things. But I have many problems with latex output from Maple. I am using the latest version 18.01. Either way, was hoping for some automated solution or a way to compile the above in Latex as I have no control of what Maple outputs for its Latex. I thought it was amsmath, since the error says `Package amsmath Error: `. thanks

Comment: if maple isn't following the "current" standard syntax (which hasn't been updated since at least 1999), they should be told so, and asked to please mend their ways.

Comment: @barbarabeeton That request to maple might carry more weight coming from you than from the OP.

Comment: @EthanBolker -- i'm considering that.  the fact that we don't use maple here directly does mean that i'll have to do some research before writing to them though, so it can't happen right away.

Comment: I don't think the edit is good, as the errors are on the Maple side and they are off-topic here.

Comment: @egreg no problem, will remove them. thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The old `\cases{...}` form is an unabridged copy of the same macro in Plain TeX and is in the LaTeX kernel just because it was in Plain.

The environment form was introduced in `amsmath.sty` issued, if I remember correctly, in 1994, so I'm quite surprised that Maple insists in using deprecated commands and doesn't exploit `amsmath`.

What you want can be done, though. Possibly not as robust as one can hope, but it's a hack, after all.

The key is using `mathtools` in order to overcome the deficiencies of the old `\cases` command.

```
\documentclass[11pt,notitlepage]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,mathtools}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\let\amscases\cases
\makeatletter
\def\cases{\@ifnextchar\bgroup\plaincases\amscases}
\def\plaincases#1{\begin{cases*}#1\end{cases*}}
\makeatother



\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
x-
\cases{-2\,\sqrt {-y \left( x \right) }&$y \left( x \right) \leq 0$\cr 
2\,\sqrt {y \left( x \right) }&$0<y \left( x \right) $\cr}+{\it \_C1}=0_{{1}}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
x-
\begin{cases}
  -2\,\sqrt {-y \left( x \right) }&y \left( x \right) \leq 0\\
  2\,\sqrt {y \left( x \right) }&0<y \left( x \right) 
\end{cases}+{\it \_C1}=0_{{1}}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
x-
\begin{cases}
  -2\sqrt{-y(x)} & y(x) \leq 0\\
  2\sqrt{y(x)}   & 0 < y (x)
\end{cases}+\mathit{\_C1}=0_{1}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

The second example shows that the environment form is typeset correctly, the third is the “really correct” LaTeX input, without useless `\left` and `\right` and the obsolete and deprecated `\it` command.

[image]

Comment: you're a bit behind the times, @egreg.  the first formal edition of "joy of tex" is copyright 1982, and there was an earlier draft version that circulated under what i believe may have been a slightly earlier copyright.  (but you're right that maple should have fixed this by now!)

Comment: @barbarabeeton I was referring to `amstex` for LaTeX. I'm not sure about the release date of version 1.0. Of course AMS-TeX appeared much earlier than 1990 (I started using it in 1985).

Comment: i've just checked (still have access to old versions).  `amstex.sty` never had the environment form, always `\cases`, up through the last release in 1999 (which was declared obsolete and deprecated long before that, but remained in circulation so that old documents wouldn't become unprocessable).  the environment form was introduced with `amsmath`, along with a general cleanup removing all applicable command forms in favor of environments.  but you're correct that the first ams-latex appeared in 1990; the version 1.0 user's guide is dated july 1990.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Thanks for the information; I'll update my answer. Is 1994 the right release date for `amsmath`?

Comment: there was almost certainly a preliminary release of `amamath` in 1994; the first printed ams-latex manual for version 1.2 has the date january 1995.  (sadly, a printed date was omitted from some later, intermediate versions; i think this is always a bad idea, but there has been strong disagreement from the contemporaneous management during some periods.)

Answer (score 3):

It should be easy to replace all occurences of `\cases` by, say, `\Cases`. Then, with some additional modifications:

```
\documentclass[11pt,notitlepage]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
%smart renewcommand here? or \let?
\def\Cases#1{\begin{cases}#1\end{cases}}
\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
x-
\Cases{-2\,\sqrt {-y \left( x \right) }&y \left( x \right) \leq 0\cr 
2\,\sqrt {y \left( x \right) }&0<y \left( x \right) \cr}+{\it \_C1}=0_{{1}}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: But you changed the actual Maple code manually? Changed `cases` to `Cases` in the code. The original Maple output used `cases` not `Cases` as you have there. The whole point is to not have to edit any of the Maple output as this will run many times and I can't edit the output manually each time I run the script. Thanks.

Comment: @Nasser Yes, but it is one global change easy to do by any good text editor.

Comment: I understand, but as I said, this is automated and a script runs over them many times. So a solution that can avoid having to do any manual step, even if it is one step will be easier for me.

Comment: Your scripted workflow could incorporate a `python` or `sed` or `awk` script to automate the substitution.